# Creating an SQL file per EER diagram in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL Workbench project with multiple EER diagrams.

In diagram 1, I have `table1` and `table2`.
In diagram 2, I have `table3`.

I would like to generate an SQL CREATE script for diagram 1 containing `table1` and `table2`.
I also want to generate a separate script for diagram 2 containing `table3`.

In `File > Export > Forward Engineer SQL Create Script`, it always includes all tables from all diagrams, and I need to manually select and deselect tables when creating the scripts, which is quite cumbersome.

Is there a way to automatically generate `CREATE` SQL scripts base on a EER diagram basis?

Answer (score 0):

Creating export scripts based on their placement on a diagram is not supported in MySQL Workbench. File a feature request at http://bugs.mysql.com to get such a feature to the planning.

Comment: Definitely a missing feature.